# What are some good books for learning IBM Websphere Application Server?

Tags: websphere

I am beginning to use IBM's WAS servers at work.  I've been given some point and click instructions on how to get what I need done, but I really do not understand the underlying architecture of this program.  What are some good books for learning WAS?  I do not plan on writing any code, so that type of reading would not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think "[Application Architecture for WebSphere: A Practical Approach to Building WebSphere Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137129262)" by Joey Bernal is outstanding.

He does a great job describing the application architecture and web application development. The first two chapters are really outstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not just limited to books, I would also recommend checking the [IBM developerWorks Technical library](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/?sort_by=&show_abstract=true&show_all=&search_flag=&contentarea_by=WebSphere&search_by=&product_by=WebSphere%20Application%20Server&topic_by=-1&type_by=All%20Types&ibm-search=Search). There is plenty of content available there for free.

Answer (score 0):

I think Marc is asking for a book that will help him understand the architecture of WAS itself, not the application, altought understanding how apps work will of course help with understanding how the core (java engine) works and will bring some light on the mechanism used by WAS. However for a beginner i would recoomend WAS 6.1 System Management And Configuration.pdf and other redbooks - in that particullar you should be able to find all neccessary data to start your day-by-day work with WAS.